# Codeigintier Loop Through Multidimensional Array Getting Error Undefined index:

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [OrderID] => 94
        [AccountID] => 1
        [UserID] => 1
        [OrderStatus] => POSTED
        [OrderType] => Buy
        [Subtotal] => 231.91
        [ExchangeFee] => 5.00
        [OrderFee] => 0.00
        [TotalFee] => 5.00
        [GrandTotal] => 226.91
        [Notes] => 
        [DateCreated] => 2013-12-11 10:51:27
        [OrdersDetail] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [OrderDetailID] => 96
                        [OrderID] => 94
                        [CurrencyID] => 3
                        [CheckCurrency] => 1
                        [TransTypeID] => 4
                        [Credit] => 300.00
                        [Rate] => 0.773044
                        [Debit] => 231.91
                        [Fee] => 5.00
                        [LineTotal] => 226.91
                        [Description] => Australian Dollar
                        [TransType] => Cash
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Which was created by a function in my model. I then have the following code in my controller.

```
$this->Data['OrdersArray'] = $this->orders->getOrdersToday('Buy');
```

I which works great. What I am trying to do is in my view use two foreach statments to parse the information in the multi array to build a list of information. And this is what I have in my view.

```
<tbody>
<? if(isset($OrdersArray) && $OrdersArray){ ?>
    <?php foreach ($OrdersArray as $key=>$item):?>
    <tr class="<?=alternator('odd','even')?>">
        <td><?=$item['OrderID']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['OrderStatus']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['UserID']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['Subtotal']?></td>
        <td><?=$item['OrderFee']?></td> 
        <td><?=$item['GrandTotal']?></td>                          
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
<? } ?>
<? if(isset($OrdersArray) && $OrdersArray){ ?>                          
    <?php foreach ($OrdersArray as $key=>$item):?>
        <tr class="<?=alternator('odd','even')?>">
            <td><?=$item['Description']?></td>
            <td><?=$item['Credit']?></td>
            <td><?=$item['Rate']?></td>                         
        </tr>                                
    <?php endforeach;?>                                                                                   
<? } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get all of this information on one line and I keep getting an Undefined index: error. So I guess my problem is I do not understand how to correctly write the foreach statements so they loop through all of the information. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are sure you will only have one index for OrdersDetail array then you could use directly ignoring the foreach loop as $item['OrdersDetail'][0]['Description'],$item['OrdersDetail'][0]['Credit'] etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OrdersDetail** data can not be accessed using same foreach. You need another foreach id there are more than one arrays at **OrdersDetail** Index.

```
<tbody>
<? if(isset($OrdersArray) && $OrdersArray){ ?>
<?php foreach ($OrdersArray as $key=>$item):?>
<tr class="<?=alternator('odd','even')?>">
<td><?=$item['OrderID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['OrderStatus']?></td>
<td><?=$item['UserID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['Subtotal']?></td>
<td><?=$item['OrderFee']?></td> 
<td><?=$item['GrandTotal']?></td>                          
</tr>
<? if(isset($item['OrdersDetail'])){ ?>
<?php foreach ($item['OrdersDetail'] as $key2=>$item2):?>
<tr class="<?=alternator('odd','even')?>">
<td><?=$item2['Description']?></td>
<td><?=$item2['Credit']?></td>
<td><?=$item2['Rate']?></td>                         
</tr>                                
<?php endforeach;?>                                                                                   
<? } ?>
<?php endforeach;?> 
<? } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked for what I needed thank you. I was not understanding that I could not just use the foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of orders and on each order you have an array of that order details for this you can do so

```
<? if(isset($OrdersArray) && $OrdersArray){ ?>
<?php foreach ($OrdersArray as $key=>$item):?>
<tr class="<?=alternator('odd','even')?>">
<td><?=$item['OrderID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['OrderStatus']?></td>
<td><?=$item['UserID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['Subtotal']?></td>
<td><?=$item['OrderFee']?></td> 
<td><?=$item['GrandTotal']?></td>
<?php if isset($item['OrdersDetail']){  ?>
<td><table>
<?php foreach($item['OrdersDetail'] as $details){
?><tr>
<td><?=$item['OrderDetailID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['OrderID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['CurrencyID']?></td>
<td><?=$item['CheckCurrency']?></td>
<td><?=$item['TransTypeID']?></td>    
<td><?=$item['Credit']?></td>
<td><?=$item['Rate']?></td>
<td><?=$item['Debit']?></td>
<td><?=$item['LineTotal']?></td>
<td><?=$item['Description']?></td>
<td><?=$item['TransType']?></td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
</table>
</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?> 
<? } ?>
```